# function getsecret is not valid at this location

Tags: azure-bicep

iam using existing secrets in keyvault for my bicep file. Since last week it's working fine. But now it's throwing error. Pls help to fix this issue.
function getsecret is not valid at this location

function getsecret is not valid at this location.

Comment: Could you share your bicep files please ?

Comment: Add the relevant part of your bicep on the post so people can try to help

Answer (score -1):

i tried to use existing secrets in key vault.since last week its working fine.currently its giving below error.

Function "getSecret" is not valid at this location. It can only be used
when directly assigning to a module parameter with a secure decorator.

My code ::adminUsername: sharedKeyVault.getSecret('vmlocaladminusername')
adminPassword: sharedKeyVault.getSecret('vmlocaladminpassword')